# Grid not showing and blank in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I opened my blender file and I saw the grid and when I went into the rendered mode in cycles everything was blank and there are lights in the scene and the sample progress doesn't change even though it is unpaused. I have turned on the grid in the overlay tab but it didn't work. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change view clip start to 0.1

[image]

Then you will see the grid again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have is that when I render it in cycles it is blank

Comment: well, to be honest you had two "questions" in one: one was: Grid not showing (this is, what i answered) and the other question was: blank in cycles. "normally" you should ask only one question here and open another for the next question.

Comment: Okay I will do that I am new to using blender.

Answer (score 0):

I switched render to EEVEE and in setting change hair type to strip:

[image]

And after that, Grass is started displaying like this:

[image]

That is mean that width of grass 10 times bigger than house. This is too heavy for Cycles, and it cannot show even one pass.  So you need to set up width like this to make the grass reasonable sized:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have is that when I render it in cycles it is blank